# Groovy way of finding largest matching list member based on members property

Tags: groovy

Is there a better way to find closest object with lesser marker?

```
class Prop implements Comparable {
  BigDecimal marker
  String value

  int compareTo(other) {
    return marker <=> other.marker
  }

}

def props = [new Prop(marker: 0G, value: "1st"),
new Prop(marker: 20G, value: "2nd"),
new Prop(marker: 30G, value: "3rd"),
new Prop(marker: 40G, value: "4th"),
new Prop(marker: 50G, value: "5th"),
new Prop(marker: 100G, value: "6th"),
new Prop(marker: 1000G, value: "7th")]

def whereAmI = 44G

def here = props.findAll{it.marker <= whereAmI}.max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated to return the correct object type, and nulls.

Assuming that order isn't guaranteed, you could use [the `inject` method](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-inject-method.html):

```
// Inject null, so if nothing is lower than max, this returns null
def here = props.inject(null){ max, it ->
    (it.marker <= whereAmI && (!max || it > max)) ? it : max
}
```

If the list is always sorted, then simply use this:

```
// Inject null, so if nothing is lower than max, this returns null
def here = props.inject(null){ max, it ->
    (it.marker <= whereAmI) ? it : max
}
```

The benefit here is you only loop over the set once, and you don't create an additional interim `List` of lesser values.

Now, depending on your list size, the argument may be that your original example is a lot easier to read, and a lot clearer.  Clarity in code can trump performance.

(Note: `inject` is Groovy's version of [reduce or fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_%28higher-order_function%29).)

Comment: Minor problem here is that you are returning a Double and not a Prop

Comment: It would be rather easy to modify.  Sorry I missed that.  Basically, replace the initial inject with the first item from the list, and compare on `max.marker`.  I'll update the example.

Comment: Ok, I did it a bit differently, and injected null, so you can tell if you are at the beginning of the list.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and updates. Just like you said "Clarity in code can trump performance" and this is a perfect example of that. Since my list is always going to be rather small, I will stick with my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to OverZealous's inject solution that works if the props list is sorted by marker.  Create a `takeWhile` method on Lists, and then take the last one less than `whereAmI`:

```
List.metaClass.takeWhile = { closure ->
    def iter = delegate.iterator()
    int i = 0
    def n = iter.next()
    while(closure.call(n)) {
        i++
        if (iter.hasNext())
            n = iter.next()
        else
            break
    }
    return delegate[0..<i]
}   

props.takeWhile { it.marker < whereAmI }[-1]           // exception if nothing matches
props.takeWhile { it.marker < whereAmI }.reverse()[0]  // null if nothing matches
```

Answer (score 0):

What a better way to do it is will depend on what you consider as better.

For code readability, I think the solution you originally proposed is very good.

The OverZealous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534964/groovy-way-of-finding-largest-matching-list-member-based-on-members-property/7535234#7535234) migth be faster but, as he mentioned, it's not as readable. And in fact, if performance really matters for that code, you should profile it to see if it's really faster.

If the `props` list is created once (or few times) but the `here` value is calculated many times, you migth consider sorting `props` and looking for `whereAmI` with a binary search. This will take log(n) time (n the size of `props`) instead of linear time.

```
// Make whereAmI a Prop to avoid defining a Comparator
def whereAmI = new Prop(marker: 44G, value: '')
def i = Collections.binarySearch(props, whereAmI)
def here = props[i >= 0 ? i : -i - 2]
```

When `whereAmI` is not in `props`, `bynarySearch` returns the negative of one plus the index where `whereAmI` should be, hence the seemingly magical `-1 -2` there.

Warning: this won't work if there is no element in `props` that is less than `whereAmI`. if that is a possibile case, you should ask for a `i == -1`. The original code assigned `null` to `here` in that case:

```
def here = i == -1 ? null : props[i >= 0 ? i : -i - 2]
```